# ios7 UITableViewCell selectionStyle won't go back to blue

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Xcode 5.0, iOS 7 and updating an existing app. `UITableView` selected row is now gray, not blue.

From what I've read they changed the default `selectionStyle` to gray. But "Blue" is still an option in IB and `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` still exists. Checking out the new HIG, it doesn't look like they removed the blue and the "Settings" app still using blue cell selection.

I've tried setting the value in IB and in code, but no luck. Any ideas on what I need to do to get the blue selection style back?

Comment: I am unable to check it out right now, but in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, it does not work to use the statement, `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;`?

Comment: Just tested it out- it does not work. I will try to figure it out and get back to you if I can fix it

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is only one selectionStyle in iOS7, to change you need to do this manually like below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    ....
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
    bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
    ....
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about trying something like this- only problem is that `blueColor` is the ugliest possible shad of blue for this. If someone wants to actually use this in an app, then it would require using RGB combos for a better color

Comment: So what I'm hearing is, blue as a default either no longer exists or isn't functioning properly. That was pretty much my conclusion too, but it seems awfully strange they wouldn't take it out of the UI or deprecate it if wasn't going to have a future.

Comment: While not overly happy with this answer, this type of approach does seem to be the only which currently works (hopefully that will change soon). So I'm marking as the accepted answer.

Comment: Great answer, I'd suggest using `[UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]` instead of `[UIColor blueColor]` though

Comment: Should really update the cell background color in `willDisplayCell:` method. From `UITableViewCell` documentation. "If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view delegate."

Comment: To top this off, add `cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` to get the white text color that used to come with it as well

Comment: Try `[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(122.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]` if you want to match Apple's default tint.

Answer (score 13):

I know this has already been answered but the last thing I wanted to do was touch all of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods. So, I used an appearance proxy in my App Delegate. I took @null's code above to set the selected background view and in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method I placed this code.

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
//the rest of null's code to make the view
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Then to make the white text hi light:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This made a global change in my app. The appearance proxy was introduced in iOS5 and Mattt has a [great article on how to use it at his NSHipster blog](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/).

Comment: I'll definitely keep this in mind the next time I need to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7):

Probably it could help you. I have my custom cell and to make it selected with needed color I have overwrite setHighlighted and setSelected now it's look like that

```
#define IOS_7 (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 ? YES : NO)


    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self changeSelectionColorForSelectedORHiglightedState:selected];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    [self changeSelectionColorForSelectedORHiglightedState:highlighted];
}

- (void)changeSelectionColorForSelectedORHiglightedState:(BOOL)state
{
    if (IOS_7) {
        if (state) {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm really late to the party, but I'll offer my IOS10 work around as well. Don't touch any of your other code, but add:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

     ... whatever else you do ...
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```