# Why can't you set the cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen the following questions, but non explain that while you can simply set `cell.SelectedStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray` or `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`, you can't set it selectionStyle to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`.

They just offer a hack without explaining. I simply want to know the **why** so that I can better understand objective-c

[UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419760/uitableviewcellselectionstyleblue-is-not-working)

[ios7 UITableViewCell selectionStyle won't go back to blue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794080/ios7-uitableviewcell-selectionstyle-wont-go-back-to-blue)

[Cannot change UITableView blue highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019834/cannot-change-uitableview-blue-highlight-color)

Comment: cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue should be placed just before return cell;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your not going to like the answer then.  As of iOS 7, setting

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellselectionStyleBlue;
```

will now give you gray.  Apple got rid of it in iOS 7, so now selectionStyleBlue no longer exists as blue.. it is gray.

Here is the quote from Apple's Documentation of the UITableViewCell Class Reference:

> - Blue
>
> The cell has a default background color when selected.
>
> In iOS 7, the selection color is no longer blue. Use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault instead.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Of course, as I'm sure you have found, you can create a UIView and set it as the background to simulate a blue selection.

Here is a link for that approach:  [UITableView cell blue highlight on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020031/3543861)

**Edit:**

Just to be clear. UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue makes the selection style gray.

There is no default method of UITableViewCell that makes selection style a blue color.

In order to make selection style any color other than the default gray, you have to create a custom UIView like in the link I provided.

Comment: Thanks!
Apple got rid of it!?! I can't make sense of what you are saying.I can see it in the `UITableView.h`:
`@property (nonatomic) UITableViewCellSelectionStyle   selectionStyle;             // default is UITableViewCellSelectionStyle*Blue*.`


ALSOOO: `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellSelectionStyle) {
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyle*Blue*,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray,
    UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)`

Comment: See my edit to the question.. UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue is actually gray.. I know it is confusing but ALL UITableViewCellSelectionStyle properties are going to be gray... from now on just pretend like UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue doesn't exist!! (bc its gray)

Comment: @asma22 Apple redesigned the UI when releasing iOS 7. They stopped using blue color for selections (they actually use a different color in every app) and the constant stopped making sense so they renamed it to `default` which is more sensible.

Comment: Can you tell me why apple has `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` in its documentation? It seems that it doesn't have ANY purpose.

Comment: I would assume so that people's apps don't crash that had set `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue` before iOS 7.. your right, basically it doesn't have ANY purpose

Comment: Super Thanks; Apple usually specifies when something is depreciated...is there anywhere in its documentation that it says such? I am not trying to be nerdy, as a newbie I am just trying to figure out how to read the public APIs of every class and come less to stackoverflow OR there is no way--this is this purely Apple's bad approach to its documentation?

Comment: Heres the documentation.. just scroll down and click on "UITableViewCellSelectionStyle" under "Constants" https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle and feel free to mark this as the correct answer :)