# Why selectionStyle has no effect?

Tags: ios, uitableview

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns a cell with `selectionStyleBlue`. But it has no effect. Gray selection style is used when selected row. Any idea why?

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

Comment: Please check user interaction is enable or not for tableview/tableviewcell

Comment: i think its return gray color when you select row?

Comment: Gray used when **selected** row.

Comment: This Will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775494/why-cant-you-set-the-cell-selectionstyle-uitableviewcellselectionstyleblue

Answer (score 0):

`selectionStyle` **UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue** is not exist now, apple restricted it to grayColor only,

so if you want to achieve selection style then give manually,

```
UIView *cellColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
cellColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // Or use RGB to exact color
cellBg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellColor;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

// Tableview delegate methods...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
var cellToDeSelect:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
cellToDeSelect.contentView.backgroundColor = colorForCellUnselected
```

}